# How to use passport with express and socket.io?

Tags: express, socket.io, passport.js

I am currently trying to set up a basic authentication system for my node.js app. For now I am using express (3.0.0rc5), passport (0.1.12) and socket.io (0.9.10) with Mongoose as Store for session data. I have also been playing around with `everyauth` but I didn't like to work with promises.

Current situation:

Authentication through passport (facebook strategy) is successful, a `session.sid` cookie is set on the client after the redirect and I am able to see a session document in my database. I can access the session cookie in `socket.io` through `socket.handshake.headers.cookie`.

If I understood the passport concept correctly, after successful `authentication passport.serializeUser` is called which enables me to add information to the session. In my case the most important information is the email, so I set the serializer up in the following way:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.email);
});
```

Now I am at the point where I have to use only the cookie information in my socket.io event to extract the email address from the session.

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    parseSignedCookie = connect.utils.parseSignedCookie,
    cookie            = require('express/node_modules/cookie');

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    if(socket.handshake.headers.cookie) {
        var cookie = cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie);
        var sessionID = parseSignedCookie(cookie['connect.sid'], 'secret');
    }
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    // so, what is supposed to be done here?
});
```

So if I am not mistaken, the task is now to use `deserializeUser` to access the corresponding email address.

How would I do that? Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Here is a solution using **Socket.IO 1.0 and Express 4.0**.  It is similar in spirit to Patrick's answer.  The trick is that since Socket.IO 1.0 has a new middleware API, we can wrap Express's middleware and put it into the Socket.IO pipeline without delving into the low-level implementation of the session stores.

```javascript
// Set up the Session middleware using a MongoDB session store
expressSession = require("express-session");
var sessionMiddleware = expressSession({
    name: "COOKIE_NAME_HERE",
    secret: "COOKIE_SECRET_HERE",
    store: new (require("connect-mongo")(expressSession))({
        url: "mongodb://localhost/DATABASE_NAME_HERE"
    })
});

// Set up the Express server
var app = require("express")()
    .use(sessionMiddleware)
    .use(passport.initialize())
    .use(passport.session())
    // ... more middleware ...
    .listen(8000);

// Set up the Socket.IO server
var io = require("socket.io")(app)
    .use(function(socket, next){
        // Wrap the express middleware
        sessionMiddleware(socket.request, {}, next);
    })
    .on("connection", function(socket){
        var userId = socket.request.session.passport.user;
        console.log("Your User ID is", userId);
    });
```

The variable **sessionMiddleware** is a function that is designed to fit directly into the Express pipeline.  It takes exactly three arguments: the request object, the response object, and a callback.

Socket.IO's pipeline expects its middleware to take only two arguments, however: the socket object (which contains the request object at *socket.request*) and a callback.  Luckily **sessionMiddleware** does not require the response object to read the session from the store, so we simply pass it an empty object as the second argument.

Note that some comments below observe that this code renders the session read-only.  This is the functionality we lose by not having a proper *response* object with Socket.IO.

In the above example I use a MongoDB session store (connect-mongo).  You can use whatever session store fits your liking.  Refer to [the Connect wiki](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki#session-stores) for a list of session stores.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what does  `sessionMiddleware(socket.request, {}, next)` do and how did you figure that out ? Thanks.

Comment: Up in the Express section, when you pass `sessionMiddleware` to `app.use(...)`, Express will call that function whenever it receives a request.  By convention, Express passes the function three arguments: the request object, the response object, and then `next` function to call when done.  Socket.IO v1.0 has a similar paradigm, but it passes two arguments instead of three: the socket object, and the `next` function.  The line you referenced translates between the two APIs.

Comment: I get a ´new TypeError("Parameter 'url' must be a string, not " + typeof url)´ error because of a mismatched pathname with socket.io 1.1.0, originating from the line ´sessionMiddleware(socket.request, {}, next);´ and raised in ´session (../server/node_modules/express-session/index.js:98:24)´. Any advice is appreciated !

Comment: @Ben - I am getting the same error. were you able to fix it?

Comment: Helo there, this answer was pretty helpful for me, but as soon as i digged further i stumbled upon a problem. i can nor modify session from inside sockets. only way i found is manually call .save() on session from mongo store, it saves, but then i can not modify tose saved values further, they are stuck on firstly saved value.

Comment: @MaxYari, sessionMiddleware only gives you read access, in most cases it's enough. Use [session.socket.io](https://github.com/wcamarao/session.socket.io) to also be able to save from inside sockets.

Comment: question: Patrick's answer clearly shows him manually going to the session store to retrieve the session information. But does this answer's  socket.io middleware functionality ("io.use(function(socket, next){
        sessionMiddleware(socket.request, {}, next);
    });")  read from MongoStore for you? or do you need to go read the session id from MongoStore yourself?

Comment: @AlexMills The session information is retrieved from your session store internally by *sessionMiddleware*.  In fact, that is exactly *sessionMiddleware*'s job for Express; we are just manipulating it to work for Socket.IO.

Comment: @ClaudiuHojda Session.socket.io is for socket.io < 1.x and it's almost depreceated

Comment: @MaxYari [session.socket.io/example-express4](https://github.com/wcamarao/session.socket.io/tree/master/example-express4) uses socket.io 1.3.x. With a middleware like this [socket.io-express-session](https://github.com/xpepermint/socket.io-express-session) you can only read, with `session.socket.io`, even if it's old style, you receive a Session instance and you can also save.

Comment: @ClaudiuHojda yep, this example really is old style and their github doc clearly stated that thsi module will be depreciated, and use sessionmiddleware for sockets instead (which seems have no suport for writing). Ah, maybe i just better to hold a simple object with session/socket.io keypair and that will fit my needs

Comment: If you put the passport middlewares into socket.io as well then you can find `client.request.user` a bit less digging, not sure if there are any advantages to this yet...

Comment: @sffc what do you think about adding linking of passport middleware alongside with session middleware to your code example? As question is about actually using passport it looks a bit incomplete with only session middleware in your answer.

Comment: I get this url-error as well ,.. :(

TypeError: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined
at Url.parse (url.js:73:11)
at urlParse (url.js:67:5)
at Array.session (node_modules/express-session/index.js:98:24)

Comment: Wonder why it's not `socket.request.user;` instead of `socket.request.session.passport.user;` ... the former seems like it's more in line with Express.js.

Comment: Is there any way to retrieve the whole user object instead of just the serialized id? That is, the object returned by `passport.deserializeUser()`?

Comment: @Kathandrax I was able to get that working by applying as middleware `sessionMiddleware`, `passport.initialize`, and `passport.session`. For `passport.initialize` and `passport.session`, I have a separate `use` clause for each that looks like this (just showing it for `initialize`, but same idea for `session`): `io.use((socket, next) => {passportLib.initialize()(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);});`

Comment: `socket.request.session.passport` is undefined after authentication unless the socket is reconnected, the problem is I connect the socket before authentication, how do I solve this?

Comment: Where do I find what to put in place of "COOKIE_NAME_HERE"? My current working express/passport/socketio code (that I'm trying to secure with authentication now) doesn't have an obvious cookie name anywhere.

Comment: @StevenKim: You can invent a cookie name for your app. The default is "session".

Answer (score 36):

I got it to work. What I had to to is get access to the sessionStore. Here is the code in case anyone else stumbles over this particular problem:

```
// # app.js

var express     = require('express'),
    routes      = require('./routes'),
    http        = require('http'),
    path        = require('path'),
    app         = express(),
    passport    = require('passport'),
    SessionMongoose = require("session-mongoose"),
    mongooseSessionStore = new SessionMongoose({
        url: "mongodb://localhost/login",
        interval: 120000 
    });

var config       = require('game/config.js'), // holds my whole server configuration
    server       = require('game/lib/server.js');

// save sessionStore to config for later access
config.setSessionStore(mongooseSessionStore);

// configure express to use passport and mongooseSessionStore
app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', config.port);
    app.set('env', config.environment);
    app.set('dbPrefix', config.dbPrefix);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({secret : 'totallysecret', store : mongooseSessionStore })),
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());    
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express['static'](path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.get('/', routes.index);

app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: 'email' }));
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', 
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/',
                                        failureRedirect: '/' })); 

// #### Init httpserver
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(app.get('port'));

// #### Server startup
server.init(httpServer);
```

My serialization functions look simple like this:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    // saves user.email to session.passport.user
    done(null, user.email);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
});
```

And finally the socket.io implementation:

```
var util              = require('util'),
    connect           = require('connect'),
    parseSignedCookie = connect.utils.parseSignedCookie,
    cookie            = require('express/node_modules/cookie'),
    io                = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);

var config = require('../config.js');  

io.configure(function () {
    io.set('authorization', function (data, callback) {
        if(data.headers.cookie) {
            // save parsedSessionId to handshakeData
            data.cookie = cookie.parse(data.headers.cookie);
            data.sessionId = parseSignedCookie(data.cookie['connect.sid'], 'totallysecret');
        }
        callback(null, true);
    });

    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        // reference to my initialized sessionStore in app.js
        var sessionStore = config.sessionStore;
        var sessionId    = socket.handshake.sessionId;

        sessionStore.get(sessionId, function(err, session) {
            if( ! err) {
                if(session.passport.user) {
                    console.log('This is the users email address %s', session.passport.user);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Using the session-mongoose module I have access to:

```
sessionStore.get(sessionId, callback)
sessionStore.set(sessionId, data, callback) 
sessionStore.destroy(sessionId, callback) 
sessionStore.all(callback)    // returns all available sessions
sessionStore.clear(callback)  // deletes all session data
sessionStore.length(callback) // returns number of sessions in the
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [express-socket.io-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session). You can get the passport session user with `socket.handshake.session.passport.user` . It supports both reading and writing to the session store.

**NB: Works with express > 4.0.0 and socket.io > 1.0.0 and won't be backward compatible**

Comment: Hi, Can you give more steps on this?

Comment: I get that, but how do you get the user object and not the id. I guess you can do DB lookup but with passport it does it automatically with the session and defibrillation. With that method it **just shows the ID**