# socket.io and express 4 sessions

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io

I would like to access the express 4 session in my socket.io app.
I'm kind of new with Node and I have some troubles implementing this functionality.

I found a npm module that allows access to the express 4 session : https://www.npmjs.org/package/session.socket.io-express4 or https://github.com/eiriklv/session.socket.io

If you look at my app.js code below, I'm doing something wrong in the `session`, `sessionStore` or `cookieParser` setup because I just can't get this module working.

```
// init modules
var express = require('express');
var helmet = require('helmet');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var memoryStore = session.MemoryStore;
var app = express();

// set variables
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./openssl_keys/server_key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./openssl_keys/server_cert.pem')
};
var cookieSecret = "secret phrase";
var sessionStore = new memoryStore();

app.set('env', process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser(cookieSecret));
app.use(session({
    secret: cookieSecret,
    cookie: {httpOnly: true, secure: true},
    store: sessionStore
}));
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();

});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//routes
require('./routes/index')(app);
require('./routes/test')(app);


// starting http and https servers
var http = require('http').createServer(app).listen(8000, function(){
    console.log("http server listening on port 8000");
});
var https = require('https').createServer(options, app).listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("https server listening on port 8080"); 
});

// starting socket.io & session handler
var serverIO = require('socket.io').listen(https);
var SessionSockets  = require('session.socket.io-express4');
var io = new SessionSockets(serverIO, sessionStore, cookieParser);

io.on('connection', function(err, socket, session){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("connected");
    //console.log(session);
    socket.on('clientMessage', function(content) {
        console.log("received client message")
        console.log(content);
    });

});

module.exports = app;
```

I tried multiples possibilities like :

- Disabling `https` server.
- Setting up a `cookieParser` object with secret phrase (so it "actually" exports the secret phrase to `io = new SessionSockets(serverIO, sessionStore, cookieParser);`)
- Using minimal `cookie` options.

Anyway I'm a bit lost with this, any suggestions/critics are welcome.

---

**UPDATE**

Ok so after numerous tries I think I could get it work!

The problem is with the cookieParser initialization which the correct way seems to be :

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: "secret phrase",
    cookie: {httpOnly: true, secure: true},
    store: sessionStore
}));
var io = new SessionSockets(serverIO, sessionStore, cookieParser());
```

Notice that if I use `var io = new SessionSockets(serverIO, sessionStore, cookieParser);` (instead of `cookieParser()`) then it ain't working. **That seems to be the problem.**

If I use :

```
app.use(cookieParser("secret phrase"));
app.use(session({
    secret: "secret phrase",
    cookie: {httpOnly: true, secure: true},
    store: sessionStore
}));
var io = new SessionSockets(serverIO, sessionStore, cookieParser("secret phrase"));
```

then the module crashes with the following error message :

```
session.socket.io-express4/session.socket.io.js:41
ake.signedCookies[key] = handshake.signedCookies[key].match(/\:(.*)\./).pop();
                                                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'pop' of null
```

But if I use :

```
app.use(cookieParser("secret phrase"));
app.use(session({
    secret: "secret phrase",
    cookie: {httpOnly: true, secure: true},
    store: sessionStore
}));
var io = new SessionSockets(serverIO, sessionStore, cookieParser());
```

Then everything looks fine.

Now in the cookie-parser doc (https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) it's saying you can pass a secret key to get the cookies signed. Which is something I'd like to have.

Could someone explain me the relation with the cookie-parser secret phrase and the session secret phrase ? Do they have to be the same/different ?

Comment: See also this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24859515/1407170

Answer (score 19):

Here's my solution for the following environment:

- express 4.2.0
- socket.io 1.1.0
- cookie-parser 1.0.1
- cookie-session 1.0.2

Code:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')();
var session = require('cookie-session')({ secret: 'secret' };

...

app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(session);

...

io.use(function(socket, next) {
    var req = socket.handshake;
    var res = {};
    cookieParser(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        session(req, res, next);
    });
});
```

Then you can access the session from the socket's handshake:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("Session: ", socket.handshake.session);
});
```

For people wondering how/why this works:

- We send the `handshake` request through the cookie parser so that cookies are available
- Then we send the `handshake` through session middleware as if its a normal request
- The middleware attaches `session` to the request
- We use `handshake` because for all intents and purposes, it is a normal request, and the parser and session middleware can deal with it properly.  This is why you must access the `session` through the `handshake`

Comment: @Sean Adkinson I have no idea how to write to the cookie, can you help please? If I save data to socket.handshake.session it will not persist.

Comment: @youbetternot I'm not 100% sure because I haven't tried it, but using the websocket connection, you probably aren't going to be able to update the session cookie, because the browser isn't going to read the Set-Cookie header for a websocket message it receives.  Probably only on the initial handshake does it go through the normal process.  If you use server-cookies, you may have better luck, since session information is stored on the server, and you could update it there.  Make sense?

Comment: @SeanAdkinson OK, thanks for your replay, I am still trying to find a correct solution.

Answer (score 14):

With the new express-session middleware all you have to do is to add the IO middleware:

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
  session(socket.handshake, {}, next);
});
```

A complete example would look like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var Session = require('express-session'),
    SessionStore = require('session-file-store')(Session);
    session = Session({
      store: new SessionStore({ path: './tmp/sessions' }),
      secret: 'pass',
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: true
    });

io.use(function(socket, next) {
  session(socket.handshake, {}, next);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.emit('chat message', "UserID: " + socket.handshake.session.uid);
});
```

I created a super mini npm package [socket.io-express-session](https://github.com/xpepermint/socket.io-express-session) which works as I explained above.

Comment: This solution works a little bit better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53641007/630169

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with

- express 4.9.0
- express.io 1.1.13
- connect-redis 2.1.0
- express-session 1.8.2

What I wanted was to share sessions with a frontend and backend API through redis.
Separate machines, sharing same DB. Sessions are created and users logged in when they open page on the frontend, then the api looks up the logged in users on requests.

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')();
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

var db = require('./db')(config);

var sessionStore = session( {
        store: new RedisStore({ client: db }),
        secret: SECRET,
        cookie: { secure: false }
    }
);

app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(sessionStore);

// attach sessions to pure websocket requests
app.io.use(function(req, next) {
    var res = {};
    cookieParser(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        sessionStore(req, res, next);
    });
});
```

***Note*: I set the cookie.secure to *false* so I can test without https locally.**

Comment: io.use() accepts a socket as its first arg. The first argument to cookieParser and sessionStore should be socket.handshake. Other than that, your solution seeems to work :)

Comment: That was in the code I originally found, but it didn't quite work. Not sure why. I can try and then add it in

Answer (score 2):

express **4.13.4** / socket.io **1.4.5**

I browse all solutions and modules, but them all not working in my app. 
Finaly -

```
app.use(session({

      secret: COOKIE_SECRET,
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      store:sessionStore,
      cookie: { domain: 'localhost',secure: false } 

}));  


io.use(function(socket, next) {
                          session({
                              secret: COOKIE_SECRET,
                              resave: true,
                              saveUninitialized: true,
                              store:sessionStore,
                              cookie: { domain: 'localhost',secure: false } 
                          })(socket.handshake, {}, next);
});
```

working like a charm.

Comment: Unfortunately, it causes *MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected* nodejs error.

Answer (score 1):

This may work express 4 / socket.io 1.X
I grabbed this code form https://github.com/turbonetix/bus.io/blob/master/demo/chat/app.js

```
io.use(function (socket, next) {
 var handshake = socket.handshake;
  if (handshake.headers.cookie) {
  cookieParser()(handshake, {}, function (err) {
  handshake.sessionID = connect.utils.parseSignedCookie(handshake.cookies[config.session.key], config.session.secret);
    handshake.sessionStore = config.session.store;
    handshake.sessionStore.get(handshake.sessionID, function (err, data) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      if (!data) return next(new Error('Invalid Session'));
      handshake.session = new session.Session(handshake, data);
      next();
    });
   });
 }
 else {
  next(new Error('Missing Cookies'));
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it gave me a hard time to find the right solution. Here is what works for me :

```
/*

    Just to see, before my code : 

    var sessionStore = new mongoStore({
        db: db.connection.db,
        collection: config.sessionCollection
    });

    app.use(session({
        secret: config.sessionSecret,
        store: sessionStore
    }));

*/

io.use(function(socket, next) {

    var handshake = socket.handshake;

    if (handshake.headers.cookie) {

        cookieParser(config.sessionSecret)(handshake, {}, function(err) {

            handshake.sessionID = handshake.signedCookies['connect.sid']; // <- 'connect.sid' > your key could be different, but this is the default 
            handshake.sessionStore = sessionStore;

            handshake.sessionStore.get(handshake.sessionID, function(err, data) {

                if (err) return next(err);

                if (!data) return next(new Error('Invalid Session'));

                handshake.session = new session.Session(handshake, data);
                next();
            });
        });

    } else {

        next(new Error('Missing Cookies'));
    }
});
```

express 4.2.0 / socket.io 1.0.6

Answer (score 0):

[express-socket.io-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session) is a ready-made solution for your problem. Normally the session created at socket.io end has different sid than the ones created in express.js

Before knowing that fact, when I was working through it to find the solution, I found something a bit weird. The sessions created from express.js instance were accessible at the socket.io end, but the same was not possible for the opposite. And soon I came to know that I have to work my way through managing sid to resolve that problem. But, there was already a package written to tackle such issue. It's well documented and gets the job done. Hope it helps