# Node: How do I store data in an express session, so that I can access it from socket.io?

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io, passport.js

So, for learning purposes, I am writing a chat application with Node and Express. I use MongoDB/Mongoose, Passport for authentification, and socket.io for the actual chat part of the app.

I have a working registration/login/logout system. My problem is in the socket.io code. When I emit a message from a client, I want to know in the sever-side code, from what user the message originated. So, in PHP for example, I would save the user name in a session variable upon login, and later use it from somehwere else. So I attempted to do something similar here:

```
router.post('/',
    passport.authenticate('local',{ failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true }),
    function(req, res) {
        User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.user._id}, { lastConnection: new Date() }, {} ,function (err, user) {
            req.flash('welcomeMessage', 'Welcome ' + user.name + '!');
            req.session.user=user.name;         //Here I try saving the user name
            req.session.cookie.user=user.name;  //Same here, for testing purposes
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    });
```

But how do I access this data from within socket.io? In another Stackoverflow question, someone provided the following code for exposing the express session to socket.io:

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    var req = socket.handshake;
    var res = {};
    cookieParser(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        session(req, res, next);
    });
});
```

This permits me to access the session:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    //Express session:
    console.log("Session: ", socket.handshake.session);
```

Which gives me this output:

```
Session: {cookie:
    { path: '/',
      _expires: null,
      originalMaxAge: null,
      httpOnly: true
    }
}
```

This does not contain the added data. My guess is, this is the session at the point where my application starts, before I did performed a login, and therefore before any data was added to the session.

Unfortunately, I'm at a loss on how to proceed. I'm grateful for any suggestion :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [socket.io and express 4 sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494016/socket-io-and-express-4-sessions)

Comment: As I mentioned, some of the code bits in my post are from that question. I furthermore explain in my post why this does not solve my problem...

Answer (score -1):

In your Session Initialisation change default httpOnly: false settings to true.

Since, it is strict httpOnly it is denying AJAX request.

In your app.js or server.js where you're initialising Session do something like this.

`var session = expressSession({ 
    secret: 'secret key', 
    key: 'express.sid',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {httpOnly: false}
});`

Note: cookie: { httpOnly: false } is important, rest code is for example.

Thanks.