# Is this a sound authentication scheme for Node.js and Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, socket.io, redux

I am trying to setup a user login system with Node.js (Express), Socket.io, and Redux/ReactJS. This is the approach I'm taking:

1. The user connects through Socket.io as soon as he/she gets to the web app.
2. Through [socketio-auth](https://github.com/facundoolano/socketio-auth) the user is required to authenticate and passes their username and password to the server.
3. Then, using [socket.io-express-session](https://github.com/xpepermint/socket.io-express-session), like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29448630/2590203), I set a cookie with the user's username and password, so that every time they come back to the website they can be re-authenticated through [socketio-auth](https://github.com/facundoolano/socketio-auth). (I realize I could probably save a unique token in the cookie instead, would this be better?)
4. On the server, upon authentication, I just save their details with their socketId to the Redux store for use with every Socket.io request while the session lasts.

Assuming this is all done over `SSL`, is this safe? What changes would you suggest? I'm trying to make it as simple as possible yet still very safe.

Comment: I love your project. The point #3 is for sure unsafe. But I wonder what is a correct solution. Most certainly a temporary token. You make me realize that I don't really know how all these website we're logged in are using for this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like point 3, with Local Storage, is the best way to go for now.

See someone else interrogation: https://github.com/hueniverse/hawk/issues/138#issuecomment-196989520