# Socket IO using express session - socket.request.res undefined

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, express-session

I am currently trying to implement session management using express 4.x and socket io 1.4, referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532692/how-to-share-sessions-with-socket-io-1-x-and-express-4-x). The problem is that the second argument to the express session function is the res (response) object which is returning 'undefined' in my route. Is this question outdated or am I doing something wrong?

```
var http = require('http');

var session = require('express-session')(
{
  saveUninitialized : false,
  resave:false,
  secret:'secretstuff',
  cookie : {
    path : '/'
  }
}
);

var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(session)

var http_server = http.createServer(app);

var io = require('./sockets')(http_server,session);
```

here is my sockets.js

```
var Server = require('socket.io');

module.exports = function(http_server, session)
{
   var io = new Server(http_server);

   io.use(function(socket,next){

      //socket.request.res === undefined
      session(socket.request, socket.request.res,next);
   })

}
```

which is where I get

> Uncaught TypeError: argument res is required

Comment: same issue, still relevant

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem as well! I had it working a while back ago, but I don't know what's changed.

Comment: The answer, get rid of `socket.request.res` and just use `{}`, it's gawwbage!!....https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2971

`session(socket.request, socket.request.res,next) -> session(socket.request, {},next)`

Comment: @indospace.io I think Your comment could be added as an answer. However I've found a little bit better workaround, see mine answer below.

Answer (score 7):

`sessionMiddleware()` function proposed in many sources worked fine for me:

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});
```

with web `socket.io-client` <=> `socket.io` node.js server until I added `socket.io-client-cpp` application to the chain - server crashed on `socket.io-client-cpp` connection with above error:

> ```
> TypeError: argument res is required
> ```

in `sessionMiddleware()` function. People suggest to remove `socket.request.res` from the middleware completely:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29448630/630169
- https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2971#issuecomment-326084664

and replace with `{}`. However think it could be changed to slightly better variant in case somebody still need and use `socket.request.res`:

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res || {}, next);
});
```

This works fine for me!