# How to maintain users socketid in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am new in nodejs so may be it's question sounds weird but thing what i need is that i want to create a chat application where user logged in then they can chat each other one to one or one to many but problem is that if user refresh the browser then how can i maintain socket id of user list which i maintain in server side here is my code which i used

**Server Side**

```
var app = require('express')();
var fs = require('fs');
var forceSsl = require('express-force-ssl');

app.use(forceSsl);
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt')
};
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app).listen(3000,function(){
        console.log("Https server started on port 3000");
});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


var sockets = {}; 
var users = {};
io.on('connection', function(socket)
{
    console.log("Hi i am connected"); 
    // Emit the connected users when a new socket connects 
    for (var i in sockets) 
    { 
        socket.emit('user.add', { username: sockets[i].username, id: sockets[i].id  });    
    }    
    // Add a new user 
    socket.on('username.create', function (data) 
    { 
        socket.username    = data; 
        sockets[socket.id] = socket; 
        users[data]        = socket.id;
        io.emit('user.add',{ username: socket.username, id: socket.id }); 
    });    
    // Send the hug event to only the socket specified 
    socket.on('pm', function (data) 
    { 
         io.to(users[data.username]).emit('message', data.message);    
    }); 
    // Remove disconnected users 
    socket.on('disconnect', function () 
    { 
        delete sockets[socket.id]; io.emit('user.remove', socket.id);    
    }); 
});
```

**Client Side**

```
socket.emit('username.create', results.email);

socket.on("message", function(data) {
            //here i want to display message who send to this user
        });



        $(document).on('click','#gotou',function() 
        {
            var sendto  = $("#msgto").val();
            socket.emit("pm", {"username":sendto,"message":"Testing from "+checkusername}); 
        });
```

Comment: You can store your socket id in Session of `node js`.

Comment: is that work after refresh page ?

Comment: Check this out - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_sessions.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that, there are many `npm package` which you can use to store session Id of `Socket.IO`:

1. [socket.io-sessions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-sessions)
2. [cookie-session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494016/socket-io-and-express-4-sessions)

> [Cookie-parser and express-session come inside express package before
>   express 4.0](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/)

Check this out, middle ware ***npm package*** it may help you to resolve your issue.

[Middleware between express-session and socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session)

> Works with ***express > 4.0.0*** and ***socket.io > 1.0.0*** and won't be backward
>   compatible.

Example:

```
var app = require('express')(),
  server  = require("http").createServer(app),
  io = require("socket.io")(server),
  session = require("express-session")({
    secret: "my-secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  }),
  sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");


// Attach session
app.use(session);

// Share session with io sockets

io.use(sharedsession(session));

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    // Accept a login event with user's data
    socket.on("login", function(userdata) {
        socket.handshake.session.userdata = userdata;
        socket.handshake.session.save();
    });
    socket.on("logout", function(userdata) {
        if (socket.handshake.session.userdata) {
            delete socket.handshake.session.userdata;
            socket.handshake.session.save();
        }
    });        
});

server.listen(3000);
```

> Note - I didn't test it.This all package is implemented on Server-side.

or if you don't want to use this `npm package` then:

You can retrieve your socket id into variable and set it into `angular-local-storage`. So `angular-local-storage` store it after refreshing the page as well.

Example -

```
localStorageService.set('id', socketid);
```

Comment: i am using angularjs in frontend i just need nodejs and socket.io for chatting system so is there any appropriate solution you have for my problem ?

Comment: So you don't want to use any other `npm package` ?

Comment: no there is no problem to use any other package but how can i use into my client side this is main issue if you help me for this

Comment: this thing will be add on client side right ? then how to maintain in server side in node

Answer (score 2):

you can maintain the socket id in an array. you need to call first checkedIn event with userId to save socket id with userid.
here is the example

```
var socketids=[];
io.on('connection', function(socket)
{
socket.on('checkedIn', function (data) 
socketids[socket.id]=data.userId
})

})
```

Comment: what is browser is refresh then how can i maintain user list ?

Comment: then it's always stored you currently updated socket Id

Comment: @OsamaBari It will work only if you have opened client in one browser one tab. If same user is in different browser we need to maintain an array.