# Socket.io and sessions

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, session

I have a unique session id that I put in each request.session (with express) and I also use socket.io, where the 'connection' event is fired asynchronously and besides, the socket stuff is configured regardless to routes. I just want to store this session id of mine inside each socket that connects to server.

How do I bind these two things? I saw solutions that do that but they used default session ids by express and that's not the case here. (because I need first to have my first request from client handled first)

Comment: Have you had a look at this, https://www.npmjs.org/package/session.socket.io-express4

Comment: I think this answers your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679046/expressjssocket-ioexpress-session