# NodeJS Server Declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm fairly new to nodeJS/Express which I'm learning at the moment.

There seems to be different methods of creating a http server and I'm wondering what the difference is. E.g.....

From a socket.io tutorial:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
```

...and from a nodejs tutorial:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express.createServer();
```

Can someone explain the difference between the two, particularly in regards to the first example? I'm presuming the empty brackets after the express require is an anonymous function, but what is that performing? Why pass the app to the Server method?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725745/express-and-socket-io-declaration-and-starting-server