# Serve/Stop serve Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, passport.js, passport-local

Im wondering how can I serve socket.io only for logged users?

for now Im just adding/removing

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
</script>
```

but when I remove it after successful session, page is not loading. Any idea for using/serving socket.io only for users with passport session authentication?

Comment: Have you had a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24859515/1006854)?

Comment: Why you would like to do something like that? It's an open source library, that anyone can get from anywhere. If you are asking how to **allow connection to your socket server only to registered users** - this is entirely different.

Comment: @mef it somehow fits in my needs but I'm sure there is a possibility to simple switch on/off sockets for user. 

Currently I noticed that if I add
**/socket.io/socket.io.js** to every site and 
***var socket = io();***


will be switched on/off, everything is working ok and server don't use socket unitl I switch it on.

Comment: @AndreyPopov - thats the whole point. I want to open socket only if user is logged for sake of server resources. I dont want/need open socket for every anonymous looking my website. Any idea?

Comment: Please add details about "when I remove it after successful session, page is not loading": How do you "remove", and what do you mean by "page is not loading"?

Comment: @mef - i just dont display it in render engine :D and page is not loading - its look like JS broke and everything broke after all

Comment: What is the http status code returned by the server, is the page's html rendered and not displayed, or is the whole `<body>` empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The true answer here is to use the so called `handshake` of the `SocketIO` framework. It allows you to do some checks and **decide** if you should allow the user to connect to your server or not. The other answers around simply don't automatically allow the user to connect. But if he only opens a console and instantiates socket against your server - he's online.

Check this out: http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#use(fn:function):namespace

On each connection **attempt**, you can run a specific function to see if things are okay or not. You can then decline the connection (calling `next` with a parameter), or accept it - just call `next`.

And that's it :)

But here comes the tricky part - how to actually authenticate the user? Each socket is instantiated with a simple HTTP request from the client. It's later on upgraded to a socket connection.

If you are using some kind of database or a session, you can use one of the many modules out there. I've been using passport, so everything happens automatically. Here's more info about how to do it: https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio

```
var io           = require("socket.io")(server),
sessionStore     = require('awesomeSessionStore'), // find a working session store (have a look at the readme)
passportSocketIo = require("passport.socketio");

io.use(passportSocketIo.authorize({
    cookieParser: cookieParser,       // the same middleware you registrer in express
    key:          'express.sid',       // the name of the cookie where express/connect stores its session_id
    secret:       'session_secret',    // the session_secret to parse the cookie
    store:        sessionStore,        // we NEED to use a sessionstore. no memorystore please
    success:      onAuthorizeSuccess,  // *optional* callback on success - read more below
    fail:         onAuthorizeFail,     // *optional* callback on fail/error - read more below
}));

function onAuthorizeSuccess(data, accept){
    console.log('successful connection to socket.io');

    // The accept-callback still allows us to decide whether to
    // accept the connection or not.
    accept(null, true);

    // OR

    // If you use socket.io@1.X the callback looks different
    accept();
}

function onAuthorizeFail(data, message, error, accept){
    if(error)
        throw new Error(message);
    console.log('failed connection to socket.io:', message);

    // We use this callback to log all of our failed connections.
    accept(null, false);

    // OR

    // If you use socket.io@1.X the callback looks different
    // If you don't want to accept the connection
    if(error)
        accept(new Error(message));
    // this error will be sent to the user as a special error-package
    // see: http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket > error-object
}
```

Comment: passport.socketio - totally won!!! Thank you mate! I'm currently using passport-local strategy with postgres to maintain auth. With passport.socketio it will fit perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Pass a param to your view engine

For example, I'm using handlebars here -

```
app.get('/view', ...
    res.render('view.html', { authenticated : true } );
```

In your view

```
{{#if authenticated }}
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
</script>
{{/if}}
```

This doesn't secure your server by any means

You can also do something like -

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var connect = {{authenticated}} ;
    if(connect) {
       var socket = io();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: thats exacly what i'm doing right now. But how to protect server? 

Additionally: lets assume I want to let people  write on my chat. Now how can I assure server that some user dont change his id (how to get it from js if i dont display it???) and change login that display under his message?

Comment: Pass some token in the data. Verify if token matches the one stored in server against the user's session.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't stop anyone from writing in the console `io()` and everything will fire up :)