# Trouble getting the correct session data in socket.io from passport

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets, session, express

So I followed the first answer here - [How to use passport with express and socket.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095418/how-to-use-passport-with-express-and-socket-io)

And right now I can do socket.request.session.user and it returns me the id of the user. But that's it.. nothing else.

Which is strange because when I use req.user I get a whole user object and I can do things like req.user.id, req.user.username, etc.

When I do req.session.passport.user I only get the ID again.

So how can I sync it up with the socket.io authentication and get the full req.user object?

Comment: still haven't been able to fix the issue

Comment: Can still only get the ID from req.session.passport.user while I can get the whole user object from req.user