# JWT authentication with Passport and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, passport.js

I am developing React + Node JS + Express application that involves multiple servers. This is my 
**System Overview**. [image: System_overview]

I am using the proxy server for static page serving and user authentication. For that, I use JWT with passport JS. When a user signs in to the application I check for their token and authenticate and forward the request to the desired backend server.

After the login process successful, I want to communicate with backend servers with sockets as well. I am using socket.io how can I authenticate socket request and forward the request to the desired server.

I can send the token with the query string or set ExtraHeaders option in the socket.io-client.

I am supposed to authenticate socket request in, (I am using node-http-proxy for proxy requests).

```
server.on('upgrade', (req, socket, head) => {
// Authenticate the user and get the predefined server and proxy the request
// proxy.ws(req, socket, head, { target: 'http://localhost:4000' })
})
```

How can I use passport JS to authenticate the socket request?

Comment: this is answered in a related post : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095418/how-to-use-passport-with-express-and-socket-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095418/how-to-use-passport-with-express-and-socket-io)

Comment: @rajpatta I looked that answer. In my case, I am using JWT and not using a session. Even if I send my token with socket request, how can I verify it with the passport?