# How can I get sessions from express to socketio using passport?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, passport.js

I'm setting up a server that needs to use both socketio and express. I have done everything to be able to share sessions between the two using passport as a middleware and express session and I am reaching out to the community for help because I am unable to make it work.

I have tried many things and followed a lot a tutorials. They always end up getting a passport session inside the socketio on "connection" callback.

I am calling everything in the following order. I start by setting up express-sessions:

```
private SetupMiddleware(): void {
    this.app.use(logger("dev"));
    this.app.use(express.json());
    this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    this.cookieParser = cookieParser();
    this.app.use(this.cookieParser);
    this.app.use(fileUpload());
    // See https://medium.com/@evangow/server-authentication-basics-express-sessions-passport-and-curl-359b7456003d
    this.session = session({
      name: "trial",
      cookie: { maxAge: Application.maxAge },
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      secret: "joejeep",
});
    this.app.use(this.session);
    this.io.use((socket, next) => {
      this.session(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
    });
  }
```

Then I setup passport:

```
private SetupAuth(): void {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy.Strategy(
      (username, password, done) => {
        databaseService.CheckUserCredentials(username, password).then((res) => {
          if (res) {
            return done(null, username);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password." });
          }

        }).catch((err) => {
          return done(null, false, { message: "Could not find username '" + username + "'." });
        });
      },
    ));
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
      // TODO: Replace this with the actual user id
      done(null, user);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
      // I also noticed I can never reach this point
      done(null, id);
    });
    this.passInit = passport.initialize();
    this.passSess = passport.session();
    this.app.use(this.passInit);
    this.app.use(this.passSess);
    this.io.use((socket, next) => {
      this.passInit(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
    });
    this.io.use((socket, next) => {
      this.passSess(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
    });

  }
```

And finally, I set up the socket:

```
private SetupSocket(): void {
    this.io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      if (socket.request.session.passport) {
         //unable to reach here
      }
    });
  }
```

The problem I am facing is I am unable to get a passport object inside the socket after connection.

The output of console.log(socket.request) inside io.on("connection" ...

```
IncomingMessage {
[1]   _readableState:
[1]    ReadableState {
[1]      objectMode: false,
[1]      highWaterMark: 16384,
[1]      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
[1]      length: 0,
[1]      pipes: null,
[1]      pipesCount: 0,
[1]      flowing: true,
[1]      ended: true,
[1]      endEmitted: false,
[1]      reading: false,
[1]      sync: true,
[1]      needReadable: false,
[1]      emittedReadable: true,
[1]      readableListening: false,
[1]      resumeScheduled: true,
[1]      destroyed: false,
[1]      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
[1]      awaitDrain: 0,
[1]      readingMore: true,
[1]      decoder: null,
[1]      encoding: null },
[1]   readable: true,
[1]   domain: null,
[1]   _events: {},
[1]   _eventsCount: 0,
[1]   _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]   socket:
[1]    Socket {
[1]      connecting: false,
[1]      _hadError: false,
[1]      _handle:
[1]       TCP {
[1]         reading: true,
[1]         owner: [Circular],
[1]         onread: [Function: onread],
[1]         onconnection: null,
[1]         writeQueueSize: 0,
[1]         _consumed: true },
[1]      _parent: null,
[1]      _host: null,
[1]      _readableState:
[1]       ReadableState {
[1]         objectMode: false,
[1]         highWaterMark: 16384,
[1]         buffer: [Object],
[1]         length: 0,
[1]         pipes: null,
[1]         pipesCount: 0,
[1]         flowing: true,
[1]         ended: false,
[1]         endEmitted: false,
[1]         reading: true,
[1]         sync: false,
[1]         needReadable: true,
[1]         emittedReadable: false,
[1]         readableListening: false,
[1]         resumeScheduled: false,
[1]         destroyed: false,
[1]         defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
[1]         awaitDrain: 0,
[1]         readingMore: false,
[1]         decoder: null,
[1]         encoding: null },
[1]      readable: true,
[1]      domain: null,
[1]      _events:
[1]       { end: [Array],
[1]         finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
[1]         _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
[1]         drain: [Array],
[1]         timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
[1]         data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
[1]         error: [Function: socketOnError],
[1]         close: [Function: bound socketOnClose],
[1]         resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
[1]         pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
[1]      _eventsCount: 10,
[1]      _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]      _writableState:
[1]       WritableState {
[1]         objectMode: false,
[1]         highWaterMark: 16384,
[1]         finalCalled: false,
[1]         needDrain: false,
[1]         ending: false,
[1]         ended: false,
[1]         finished: false,
[1]         destroyed: false,
[1]         decodeStrings: false,
[1]         defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
[1]         length: 0,
[1]         writing: false,
[1]         corked: 0,
[1]         sync: false,
[1]         bufferProcessing: false,
[1]         onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
[1]         writecb: null,
[1]         writelen: 0,
[1]         bufferedRequest: null,
[1]         lastBufferedRequest: null,
[1]         pendingcb: 0,
[1]         prefinished: false,
[1]         errorEmitted: false,
[1]         bufferedRequestCount: 0,
[1]         corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
[1]      writable: true,
[1]      allowHalfOpen: true,
[1]      _bytesDispatched: 327,
[1]      _sockname: null,
[1]      _pendingData: null,
[1]      _pendingEncoding: '',
[1]      server:
[1]       Server {
[1]         domain: null,
[1]         _events: [Object],
[1]         _eventsCount: 6,
[1]         _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]         _connections: 1,
[1]         _handle: [Object],
[1]         _usingSlaves: false,
[1]         _slaves: [],
[1]         _unref: false,
[1]         allowHalfOpen: true,
[1]         pauseOnConnect: false,
[1]         httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
[1]         timeout: 120000,
[1]         keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
[1]         _pendingResponseData: 0,
[1]         maxHeadersCount: null,
[1]         _connectionKey: '6::::5000',
[1]         [Symbol(asyncId)]: 16 },
[1]      _server:
[1]       Server {
[1]         domain: null,
[1]         _events: [Object],
[1]         _eventsCount: 6,
[1]         _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]         _connections: 1,
[1]         _handle: [Object],
[1]         _usingSlaves: false,
[1]         _slaves: [],
[1]         _unref: false,
[1]         allowHalfOpen: true,
[1]         pauseOnConnect: false,
[1]         httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
[1]         timeout: 120000,
[1]         keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
[1]         _pendingResponseData: 0,
[1]         maxHeadersCount: null,
[1]         _connectionKey: '6::::5000',
[1]         [Symbol(asyncId)]: 16 },
[1]      _idleTimeout: 5000,
[1]      _idleNext:
[1]       TimersList {
[1]         _idleNext: [Circular],
[1]         _idlePrev: [Circular],
[1]         _timer: [Object],
[1]         _unrefed: true,
[1]         msecs: 5000,
[1]         nextTick: false },
[1]      _idlePrev:
[1]       TimersList {
[1]         _idleNext: [Circular],
[1]         _idlePrev: [Circular],
[1]         _timer: [Object],
[1]         _unrefed: true,
[1]         msecs: 5000,
[1]         nextTick: false },
[1]      _idleStart: 39763,
[1]      _destroyed: false,
[1]      parser:
[1]       HTTPParser {
[1]         '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
[1]         '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
[1]         '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
[1]         '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
[1]         '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
[1]         _headers: [],
[1]         _url: '',
[1]         _consumed: true,
[1]         socket: [Circular],
[1]         incoming: [Circular],
[1]         outgoing: null,
[1]         maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
[1]         onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming] },
[1]      on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
[1]      _paused: false,
[1]      read: [Function],
[1]      _consuming: true,
[1]      _httpMessage: null,
[1]      _peername: { address: '::ffff:127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv6', port: 57937 },
[1]      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 113,
[1]      [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
[1]      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 114,
[1]      [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 113 },
[1]   connection:
[1]    Socket {
[1]      connecting: false,
[1]      _hadError: false,
[1]      _handle:
[1]       TCP {
[1]         reading: true,
[1]         owner: [Circular],
[1]         onread: [Function: onread],
[1]         onconnection: null,
[1]         writeQueueSize: 0,
[1]         _consumed: true },
[1]      _parent: null,
[1]      _host: null,
[1]      _readableState:
[1]       ReadableState {
[1]         objectMode: false,
[1]         highWaterMark: 16384,
[1]         buffer: [Object],
[1]         length: 0,
[1]         pipes: null,
[1]         pipesCount: 0,
[1]         flowing: true,
[1]         ended: false,
[1]         endEmitted: false,
[1]         reading: true,
[1]         sync: false,
[1]         needReadable: true,
[1]         emittedReadable: false,
[1]         readableListening: false,
[1]         resumeScheduled: false,
[1]         destroyed: false,
[1]         defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
[1]         awaitDrain: 0,
[1]         readingMore: false,
[1]         decoder: null,
[1]         encoding: null },
[1]      readable: true,
[1]      domain: null,
[1]      _events:
[1]       { end: [Array],
[1]         finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
[1]         _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
[1]         drain: [Array],
[1]         timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
[1]         data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
[1]         error: [Function: socketOnError],
[1]         close: [Function: bound socketOnClose],
[1]         resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
[1]         pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
[1]      _eventsCount: 10,
[1]      _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]      _writableState:
[1]       WritableState {
[1]         objectMode: false,
[1]         highWaterMark: 16384,
[1]         finalCalled: false,
[1]         needDrain: false,
[1]         ending: false,
[1]         ended: false,
[1]         finished: false,
[1]         destroyed: false,
[1]         decodeStrings: false,
[1]         defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
[1]         length: 0,
[1]         writing: false,
[1]         corked: 0,
[1]         sync: false,
[1]         bufferProcessing: false,
[1]         onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
[1]         writecb: null,
[1]         writelen: 0,
[1]         bufferedRequest: null,
[1]         lastBufferedRequest: null,
[1]         pendingcb: 0,
[1]         prefinished: false,
[1]         errorEmitted: false,
[1]         bufferedRequestCount: 0,
[1]         corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
[1]      writable: true,
[1]      allowHalfOpen: true,
[1]      _bytesDispatched: 327,
[1]      _sockname: null,
[1]      _pendingData: null,
[1]      _pendingEncoding: '',
[1]      server:
[1]       Server {
[1]         domain: null,
[1]         _events: [Object],
[1]         _eventsCount: 6,
[1]         _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]         _connections: 1,
[1]         _handle: [Object],
[1]         _usingSlaves: false,
[1]         _slaves: [],
[1]         _unref: false,
[1]         allowHalfOpen: true,
[1]         pauseOnConnect: false,
[1]         httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
[1]         timeout: 120000,
[1]         keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
[1]         _pendingResponseData: 0,
[1]         maxHeadersCount: null,
[1]         _connectionKey: '6::::5000',
[1]         [Symbol(asyncId)]: 16 },
[1]      _server:
[1]       Server {
[1]         domain: null,
[1]         _events: [Object],
[1]         _eventsCount: 6,
[1]         _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]         _connections: 1,
[1]         _handle: [Object],
[1]         _usingSlaves: false,
[1]         _slaves: [],
[1]         _unref: false,
[1]         allowHalfOpen: true,
[1]         pauseOnConnect: false,
[1]         httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
[1]         timeout: 120000,
[1]         keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
[1]         _pendingResponseData: 0,
[1]         maxHeadersCount: null,
[1]         _connectionKey: '6::::5000',
[1]         [Symbol(asyncId)]: 16 },
[1]      _idleTimeout: 5000,
[1]      _idleNext:
[1]       TimersList {
[1]         _idleNext: [Circular],
[1]         _idlePrev: [Circular],
[1]         _timer: [Object],
[1]         _unrefed: true,
[1]         msecs: 5000,
[1]         nextTick: false },
[1]      _idlePrev:
[1]       TimersList {
[1]         _idleNext: [Circular],
[1]         _idlePrev: [Circular],
[1]         _timer: [Object],
[1]         _unrefed: true,
[1]         msecs: 5000,
[1]         nextTick: false },
[1]      _idleStart: 39763,
[1]      _destroyed: false,
[1]      parser:
[1]       HTTPParser {
[1]         '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
[1]         '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
[1]         '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
[1]         '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
[1]         '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
[1]         _headers: [],
[1]         _url: '',
[1]         _consumed: true,
[1]         socket: [Circular],
[1]         incoming: [Circular],
[1]         outgoing: null,
[1]         maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
[1]         onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming] },
[1]      on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
[1]      _paused: false,
[1]      read: [Function],
[1]      _consuming: true,
[1]      _httpMessage: null,
[1]      _peername: { address: '::ffff:127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv6', port: 57937 },
[1]      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 113,
[1]      [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
[1]      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 114,
[1]      [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 113 },
[1]   httpVersionMajor: 1,
[1]   httpVersionMinor: 1,
[1]   httpVersion: '1.1',
[1]   complete: true,
[1]   headers:
[1]    { host: 'localhost:5000',
[1]      accept: '*/*',
[1]      connection: 'keep-alive',
[1]      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
[1]      'user-agent': 'python-requests/2.13.0',
[1]      cookie: 's%3AlPJ4Jj8EI0VqkaPlE17-Fz6F3ipgY7GN.hhpf9p%2FPGfxy%2BRnrGZlw1qiuNZm9eqZEJQuCsG0967s' },
[1]   rawHeaders:
[1]    [ 'Host',
[1]      'localhost:5000',
[1]      'Accept',
[1]      '*/*',
[1]      'Connection',
[1]      'keep-alive',
[1]      'Accept-Encoding',
[1]      'gzip, deflate',
[1]      'User-Agent',
[1]      'python-requests/2.13.0',
[1]      'cookie',
[1]      's%3AlPJ4Jj8EI0VqkaPlE17-Fz6F3ipgY7GN.hhpf9p%2FPGfxy%2BRnrGZlw1qiuNZm9eqZEJQuCsG0967s' ],
[1]   trailers: {},
[1]   rawTrailers: [],
[1]   upgrade: false,
[1]   url: '/socket.io/?transport=polling&EIO=3&t=1554861396.1907172',
[1]   method: 'GET',
[1]   statusCode: null,
[1]   statusMessage: null,
[1]   client:
[1]    Socket {
[1]      connecting: false,
[1]      _hadError: false,
[1]      _handle:
[1]       TCP {
[1]         reading: true,
[1]         owner: [Circular],
[1]         onread: [Function: onread],
[1]         onconnection: null,
[1]         writeQueueSize: 0,
[1]         _consumed: true },
[1]      _parent: null,
[1]      _host: null,
[1]      _readableState:
[1]       ReadableState {
[1]         objectMode: false,
[1]         highWaterMark: 16384,
[1]         buffer: [Object],
[1]         length: 0,
[1]         pipes: null,
[1]         pipesCount: 0,
[1]         flowing: true,
[1]         ended: false,
[1]         endEmitted: false,
[1]         reading: true,
[1]         sync: false,
[1]         needReadable: true,
[1]         emittedReadable: false,
[1]         readableListening: false,
[1]         resumeScheduled: false,
[1]         destroyed: false,
[1]         defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
[1]         awaitDrain: 0,
[1]         readingMore: false,
[1]         decoder: null,
[1]         encoding: null },
[1]      readable: true,
[1]      domain: null,
[1]      _events:
[1]       { end: [Array],
[1]         finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
[1]         _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
[1]         drain: [Array],
[1]         timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
[1]         data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
[1]         error: [Function: socketOnError],
[1]         close: [Function: bound socketOnClose],
[1]         resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
[1]         pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
[1]      _eventsCount: 10,
[1]      _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]      _writableState:
[1]       WritableState {
[1]         objectMode: false,
[1]         highWaterMark: 16384,
[1]         finalCalled: false,
[1]         needDrain: false,
[1]         ending: false,
[1]         ended: false,
[1]         finished: false,
[1]         destroyed: false,
[1]         decodeStrings: false,
[1]         defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
[1]         length: 0,
[1]         writing: false,
[1]         corked: 0,
[1]         sync: false,
[1]         bufferProcessing: false,
[1]         onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
[1]         writecb: null,
[1]         writelen: 0,
[1]         bufferedRequest: null,
[1]         lastBufferedRequest: null,
[1]         pendingcb: 0,
[1]         prefinished: false,
[1]         errorEmitted: false,
[1]         bufferedRequestCount: 0,
[1]         corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
[1]      writable: true,
[1]      allowHalfOpen: true,
[1]      _bytesDispatched: 327,
[1]      _sockname: null,
[1]      _pendingData: null,
[1]      _pendingEncoding: '',
[1]      server:
[1]       Server {
[1]         domain: null,
[1]         _events: [Object],
[1]         _eventsCount: 6,
[1]         _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]         _connections: 1,
[1]         _handle: [Object],
[1]         _usingSlaves: false,
[1]         _slaves: [],
[1]         _unref: false,
[1]         allowHalfOpen: true,
[1]         pauseOnConnect: false,
[1]         httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
[1]         timeout: 120000,
[1]         keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
[1]         _pendingResponseData: 0,
[1]         maxHeadersCount: null,
[1]         _connectionKey: '6::::5000',
[1]         [Symbol(asyncId)]: 16 },
[1]      _server:
[1]       Server {
[1]         domain: null,
[1]         _events: [Object],
[1]         _eventsCount: 6,
[1]         _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]         _connections: 1,
[1]         _handle: [Object],
[1]         _usingSlaves: false,
[1]         _slaves: [],
[1]         _unref: false,
[1]         allowHalfOpen: true,
[1]         pauseOnConnect: false,
[1]         httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
[1]         timeout: 120000,
[1]         keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
[1]         _pendingResponseData: 0,
[1]         maxHeadersCount: null,
[1]         _connectionKey: '6::::5000',
[1]         [Symbol(asyncId)]: 16 },
[1]      _idleTimeout: 5000,
[1]      _idleNext:
[1]       TimersList {
[1]         _idleNext: [Circular],
[1]         _idlePrev: [Circular],
[1]         _timer: [Object],
[1]         _unrefed: true,
[1]         msecs: 5000,
[1]         nextTick: false },
[1]      _idlePrev:
[1]       TimersList {
[1]         _idleNext: [Circular],
[1]         _idlePrev: [Circular],
[1]         _timer: [Object],
[1]         _unrefed: true,
[1]         msecs: 5000,
[1]         nextTick: false },
[1]      _idleStart: 39763,
[1]      _destroyed: false,
[1]      parser:
[1]       HTTPParser {
[1]         '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
[1]         '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
[1]         '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
[1]         '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
[1]         '4': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
[1]         _headers: [],
[1]         _url: '',
[1]         _consumed: true,
[1]         socket: [Circular],
[1]         incoming: [Circular],
[1]         outgoing: null,
[1]         maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
[1]         onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming] },
[1]      on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
[1]      _paused: false,
[1]      read: [Function],
[1]      _consuming: true,
[1]      _httpMessage: null,
[1]      _peername: { address: '::ffff:127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv6', port: 57937 },
[1]      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 113,
[1]      [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 0,
[1]      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 114,
[1]      [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 113 },
[1]   _consuming: false,
[1]   _dumped: true,
[1]   _query: { transport: 'polling', EIO: '3', t: '1554861396.1907172' },
[1]   res:
[1]    ServerResponse {
[1]      domain: null,
[1]      _events: { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
[1]      _eventsCount: 1,
[1]      _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]      output: [],
[1]      outputEncodings: [],
[1]      outputCallbacks: [],
[1]      outputSize: 0,
[1]      writable: true,
[1]      _last: false,
[1]      upgrading: false,
[1]      chunkedEncoding: false,
[1]      shouldKeepAlive: true,
[1]      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
[1]      sendDate: true,
[1]      _removedConnection: false,
[1]      _removedContLen: false,
[1]      _removedTE: false,
[1]      _contentLength: null,
[1]      _hasBody: true,
[1]      _trailer: '',
[1]      finished: true,
[1]      _headerSent: true,
[1]      socket: null,
[1]      connection: null,
[1]      _header: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Length: 99\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\nSet-Cookie: io=cR5UsvmhPlsVQFwNAAAA; Path=/; HttpOnly\r\nDate: Wed, 10 Apr 2019 01:56:36 GMT\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
[1]      _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
[1]      _sent100: false,
[1]      _expect_continue: false,
[1]      statusMessage: 'OK',
[1]      statusCode: 200,
[1]      [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: null },
[1]   cleanup: [Function: cleanup],
[1]   secret: 'joejeep',
[1]   cookies: {},
[1]   signedCookies: {},
[1]   _parsedUrl:
[1]    Url {
[1]      protocol: null,
[1]      slashes: null,
[1]      auth: null,
[1]      host: null,
[1]      port: null,
[1]      hostname: null,
[1]      hash: null,
[1]      search: '?transport=polling&EIO=3&t=1554861396.1907172',
[1]      query: 'transport=polling&EIO=3&t=1554861396.1907172',
[1]      pathname: '/socket.io/',
[1]      path: '/socket.io/?transport=polling&EIO=3&t=1554861396.1907172',
[1]      href: '/socket.io/?transport=polling&EIO=3&t=1554861396.1907172',
[1]      _raw: '/socket.io/?transport=polling&EIO=3&t=1554861396.1907172' },
[1]   sessionStore:
[1]    MemoryStore {
[1]      domain: null,
[1]      _events:
[1]       { disconnect: [Function: ondisconnect],
[1]         connect: [Function: onconnect] },
[1]      _eventsCount: 2,
[1]      _maxListeners: undefined,
[1]      sessions:
[1]       { 'lPJ4Jj8EI0VqkaPlE17-Fz6F3ipgY7GN': '{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":1800,"expires":"2019-04-10T01:56:34.019Z","secure":false,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"passport":{"user":"fireyoshiqc"}}' },
[1]      generate: [Function] },
[1]   sessionID: '4epVaSDpxEGNxjwKZktGJYG0GbSGSvIN',
[1]   session:
[1]    Session {
[1]      cookie:
[1]       { path: '/',
[1]         _expires: 2019-04-10T01:56:38.004Z,
[1]         originalMaxAge: 1800,
[1]         httpOnly: true,
[1]         secure: false } } }
```

Comment: Look at this might help u https://stackoverflow.com/a/24859515/7482427

Comment: That is exactly what I have done. It does not work @ShivamSood

Comment: @ShivamSood can you spot any difference in what I have done and their suggestion ? I cannot find any difference

Comment: Just Confirming are you using [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) package? It really would make your life easy

Comment: Yes I am @ShivamSood

Comment: u are not passing ur `SetupAuth` as a middleware thats why ur passport is not working and socket.io is not able to initialize passport. U are making everything correctly just pass the `SetupAuth` using `app.use` in `SetupMiddleware` method

Comment: Hello Sorry .. Not sure I follow u on this. In the SetupAuth method I call use for passport init and passport session. Why would calling use with the SetupAuth method would work ? @ShivamSood

Comment: But u need to pass passport as a middleware in express for express to be able to use it what I mean is are u calling setup auth somewhere?

Comment: Oh yes yes, I am calling the three methods in the order I displayed them @ShivamSood

Comment: Can u explain what error do u get or try to console.log(socket.request.session.passport) what do u get

Comment: It is undefined @ShivamSood. Plus The function derserializeUser is not called when socket connects. I am unable to make it work :/

Comment: @ShivamSood Please have look at the updated post :)

Comment: I don't know if we can do this but i have a hunch that u need to do something like `app.use(SetupAuth())` I highly doubt we can do this but i have the feeling we need to do this because if u see ur console.log u can see u have `session` variable but u don't have passport in it

Comment: @ShivamSood I tried actually but it doesn't work :/ I dont get it

Comment: I think its too much to ask but do u have source code on github i want to try and run it on my pc and debug it. Its getting interesting

Comment: @ShivamSood    were you able to figure this out? I am having the same issue but no solution and I am getting frustrated

Comment: @Zia, If you can make a question, will have a look at it. I have no recollection of this issue at this point.

Comment: @ShivamSood I already have a question, and I haven't got a solution yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65059578/socket-request-user-undefined-in-passport-js-socket-io-and-express please take a look at it and help me if you can. Thanks