# Passport not showing up in session socket.io

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session-cookies

**The Problem** 
I am trying to authenticate users based on my express session similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095418/how-to-use-passport-with-express-and-socket-io) post. In http request this is what req.session returns I also connected my mongo store to hold sessions but it also behaves like socket session returning only cookie without session information.

```
//user not authenticated    
Session {
 cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true },
 passport: {}
        }
//user authenticated
Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true },
  passport: {
    user: {
      _json: [Object],
      id: '76561198298457222',
    }
```

But when i try to socket.request.session with socket io using the post refrenced passport object is not returned. But i am pretty sure that the middleware works beacuse otherwise there is no session at all.

```
// user not authenticated
Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }
}// user should be authenticated
Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }
}
```

Setup:

```
   var sessionMiddleware = session({
        secret: '<secret>',
        name: 'profile_session',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
    })
    app.use(sessionMiddleware);
io.use(function (socket, next) {
    // Wrap the express middleware
    sessionMiddleware(socket.request, {}, next);
})
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected id:', socket.id);
    console.log(socket.request.session)

});
```

Comment: try `socket.handshake.session`

Comment: Nope, not even session is mounted there

Answer (score 0):

It seems like problem is `saveUninitialized` is set to true and it saves the session even when there is no user logged in. Also u can use middleware in the `io` and get the user information.

```
var sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: '<secret>',
    name: 'profile_session',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
})

const wrap = (middleware) => (socket, next) => middleware(socket.request, {}, next);
io.use(wrap(sessionMiddleware));
io.use(wrap(passport.initialize()));
io.use(wrap(passport.session()));

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    const session = socket.request.session;
    const user = socket.request.user
    console.log(session)
    console.log(user)
})
```